# How to smooth a continous/closed curve with few points?

Tags: d3.js, plot, geometry, plotly.js

I am using Plotly.js/D3.Js.

I have the following points:

```
let points = [[38.92,8.94],[35.05,15.57],[33.17,15.57],[32.43,12.38],[32.23,10.47],[32.23,9.79],[36.7,8.26],[38.92,8.26],[38.92,8.94]];
```

I would like to create a smooth shape that encompasses these points.

If I create a curve function like so:

```
 const fitCurve = d3.line()
                .x((p) => p[0])
                .y((p) => p[1])
                .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed);
```

the outcome is as you would expect, a straight line between each point

[image: Linear curve]

Changing the curve function from [`d3.curveLinearClosed`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveLinearClosed) to [`d3.curveBasisClosed`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveBasisClosed) very effectively smoothes the curve but seemingly at the cost of the inputted points now being "control points" of a B-spline meaning that the shape drawn is within the points, at least partly and doesn't necessarily intersect with each point.

[image: Basis closed curve]

Changing the curve function to [`d3.curveCatmullRomClosed`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveCatmullRom) less effectively smoothes the curve but at least the shape contains all the inputted points.

[image: CatMullrom closed curve]

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: You could potentially improve the result by playing with [the `alpha` parameter](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveCatmullRom_alpha) but I think this is generally the trade off you're going to get.